# Android and Java: cross-platform properties loading

Tags: java, android, properties

I'm building a framework for both Java and Android. One of the feature I'd like to add to it needs to load a property file from the project itself.

In Android I can do it this way:

```
AssetManager assetManager = MyApp.getContext().getAssets();
InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("path to properties");
properties.load(inputStream);
```

and in Java I can do:

```
InputStream fis = getClass().getResource("path to properties").openStream();
properties.load(fis);
```

Is there any way I can make the properties loading cross-platform (possibly keeping the Android standard structure)? I haven't found anything on Google.

The question is mainly android-related because I think I should be able to use the Java method assuming the properties are on the classpath.

Thank you.

Comment: Open a different `InputStream` based on Android SDK level, if it's above 1 - query the asset from Context, otherwise fallback to the Java solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, using your solution I'll still have dependencies from Android context and how can I resolve them if I'm using the framework to work only with Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting a resource from the classpath(e.g. doing getClass().getResource()) and getting a resource from the file system(using Android assets) are fundamentally different. The classpath does not assume a filesystem, although with standard Java I guess you will not run into troubles quickly(if your framework would be used in an OSGi container, which has different class path rules, you will).

Hence, I’m wondering why for Android the files you are referencing are on the file system(in the assets) while for Java they are on the classpath?

I think it might be best to just put these files on the classpath for Android as well? If this is not possible, maybe use a file-based approach for those and configure the base folder somewhere?

Comment: Your answer is really interesting... I thought that the asset folder is itself under Android classpath since the path is src/main/assets, I'm using that folder because it seems that's the standard according to the documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/index.html?hl=ko

Comment: Yes it is - together with res/raw - the standard location to add raw files to your Android app. However, neither of them is a way of putting files on the classpath. Usually, raw files are not put on the classpath unless they are config files or something.

Comment: I get it. I'm used to Maven in which you put your resources under src/main/resources and it addes automatically that folder to the classpath. I thought Gradle did the same with all the folders under src but I guess I'm wrong. I could probably write a build script to do so but I guess that would be not much user-friendly for the framework so I'll probably go with two different releases, one for Java and one for android. Thank you.